# Obtaining direct download link for an embedded Kaltura video

Tags: video-streaming, download, kaltura, embedded-video

I'm looking at some embedded Kaltura videos and trying to obtain a direct download link.

For example, here is a link to an embedded video:
https://www.premierchristianradio.com/Shows/Saturday/Unbelievable/Conference-Videos/Os-Guinness-Is-It-Fools-Talk-Unbelievable-Conference-2014

I found on gitHub that someone determined the source link to be: 
http://cfvod.kaltura.com/pd/p/618072/sp/61807200/serveFlavor/entryId/1_a52wc67y/v/2/flavorId/0_a6xfygse/name/a.mp4

How do I come up with this source link to a kaltura video in general and how do I determine the fill in parameters/variables to the API?  Can someone please walk me through?

I tried using "inspect" and source code option but its too complicated for me (I am not a coder).  I also tried using the network tab to see data streaming but that didn't work.

Best I got so far are these links:

https://github.com/kaltura/DeveloperPortalDocs/blob/master/documentation/Deliver-and-Distribute-Media/how-retrieve-download-or-streaming-url-using-api-calls.md

https://knowledge.kaltura.com/faq/how-retrieve-download-or-streaming-url-using-api-calls

But I am having trouble determining the values to the API call from the source code.

I'm just trying to do this to download an embedded video. If you know of any other tool or something, that would be great. I just didn't find any of them picking the video up.

Thank you in advance! I appreciate your time/help.

Comment: When you do API call for service `baseentry` with action `get` and send your entry ID you should get download URL for the source. Notice that the entry ID can be taken from the network capture in your page (look for the string entry ID). In order to get the API to work you should also have KS (entitle for this data) as parameter in the API call

Answer (score 60):

This is really late but I managed to figure it out and it might help others. For Google Chrome (similar for other browsers):

1. Open the inspect tab (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>), go to the network tab, and filter on only XHR;
2. Click to a random part in the video and you should see a few new entries. Mouse over each looking for one starting with `https://cfvod.kaltura.com/scf/hls/p/...` This is the next few seconds of video your browser just buffered;
3. Copy the link and replace the `scf/hls` at the beginning of the link with `pd`, i.e. `https://cfvod.kaltura.com/pd/p/...` and you're left with the source link.

You can then paste it in as a url to be able to right click and save, or whatever else you want to do.

Comment: This is the easiest way -- hands down.  I've tried several different methods.

Comment: Perfect. How did you figure out which parts of the URL to replace with what?

Comment: This method works perfectly, tested it on a few different videos from different users (within the same organization using Kaltura as host for video sharing).

Comment: quick script that helps -- grab the URL as specified, then pass in at parm 1, along with parm2 a file name.


`echo $1 | sed 's/\scf\/hls/\pd/' | xargs -L 1 curl -o "$2.mp4" -L
`

Comment: @ShawnCicoria - Where should I run this script?

Comment: @PavithranRavichandiran In a Linux/Unix terminal/shell. However I had to replace `fhls` with `pd`.

Comment: @edimshuffling I love! And also curious how you figured it out.

Answer (score 13):

Next to [the answer of edimshuffling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65671181) you can also use tools provided by Kaltura themselves. Using [this kWidget](https://web.archive.org/web/20211014035332/https://player.kaltura.com/kWidget/tests/kWidget.getSources.html) you can download the video files in different formats. You can get the `partnerId` and `entryId` from the link that you can get by observing the network tab in the developer tools section of your browser (as described by edimshuffling).

For information on what part of the url is what parameter you should look at this [documentation](https://knowledge.kaltura.com/help/how-to-retrieve-the-download-or-streaming-url-using-api-calls).

Comment: Very useful for getting the best bitrate and res! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I found the method described by @edimshuffling helpful but it didn't quite work. My links were in the following form:

`https://cfvod.kaltura.com/hls/p/<other link text>/name/a.mp4/seg-1-v1-a1.ts`

Here is my full method for Chrome:

1. open developer tools <kbd>F12</kbd>, go to network tab
2. reload page
3. play video, look for ts entries in left pane, e.g. seg-11-v1-a1.ts, click on name
4. copy request URL in right pane e.g. `https://cfvod.kaltura.com/hls/p/<link text>/name/a.mp4/seg-11-v1-a1.ts`
5. paste this in new browser window
6. remove "hls" at beginning of link and final subdirectory e.g. `https://cfvod.kaltura.com/hls/p/<link text>/name/a.mp4/seg-11-v1-a1.ts` becomes
   `https://cfvod.kaltura.com/p/<more link text>/name/a.mp4`
7. load page
8. MP4 can now be downloaded by clicking Download on HTML player controls (three dots menu)

Answer (score 4):

You can download the video with this Firefox/Chrome browser webextension/addon.

`https://www.downloadhelper.net/`

Obviously you can also check the download URL within the popup of the addon.

You need to install a companion app to download.

Comment: that method is useless if I want to download a video and I have source Link too then i can just open the source link in a browser and after right-clicking on it i will see "save video as" option and after clicking on it , the video will start downloading

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It really works for Kaltura.

Answer (score 1):

Shawn Cicoria posted a useful bash script, but that didn't work, as it only downloaded a few seconds of the video. I changed it to:

```
echo $1 | sed 's/scf\/hls/\pd/' | xargs -L 1 curl -o "$2.mp4" -L
```

And just follow the method of copying from the network tab in inspector to get the link.